# Is there a version of offsetof that applies to methods?

Tags: c++, reflection

Given the struct:

```
struct Struct {
     int _a;

     int a () { return _a; }
};
```

One is able to get the offset of `_a` with `offsetof( Struct, _a )`.

How would I go about doing the same for something like `&Struct::a`?

Comment: Member function doesn't have an offset, as they aren't really stored in the objects themselves. What is the problem you want to solve using `offsetof` on a member function? Please ask about it directly instead.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The function logic only exists once for the function, not once per object. You cannot determine the offset of something that's not part of the object.

Comment: Are you looking for pointer on member function (`int (Struct::*)() /*const*/`)?

Comment: I believe so, I'm looking for a way to do `self::type< Class >().self::member( "member", &Class::SetA, &Class::GetA );`

Comment: That looks an awful lot like runtime reflection. Like you are trying to do something "Python" in c++. These are programming languages with totally different philosophies on how to do things. C++ doesn't have runtime reflection. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: I am trying to make a hybrid of runtime and compile-time reflection.

Comment: There is no runtime reflection in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [cppreference.com's page on the `offsetof` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof): (*emphasis mine*)

> Given an object `o` of type `type` and static storage duration, `o.member` shall be an lvalue constant expression that refers to a subobject of `o`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Particularly, **if member is a static data member, a bit-field, or a member function, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about doing the same for something like &Struct::a?

You wouldn't and cannot do something like this for a member function, because the concept of "offset" doesn't make sense for a member function. Member functions aren't stored inside a class instance like non-static member variables are.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your are looking for [pointers to members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members) functions:

```
int Struct::*m = &Struct::_a;
int (Struct::*f)() = &Struct::a;
```

with usage similar to

```
Struct s;

s.*m = 42;
std::cout << (s.*f)() << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fr49P1Gqa)